# mysql query is too slow on windows but very fast on linux

Tags: mysql, windows, performance

I have a MySQL query which is working on linux server very fast and normal (less than 1 sec). But when i try to run this query on my local windows pc or my windows remote server it takes at least 40 secs for result.

Linux:

[image: linux result]

Windows:

[image: windows result]

And here is my query:

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS listings.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT images.imagelink) as images, title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag) as tags, stores.name
FROM listings LEFT JOIN bayiler ON bayiler.id = listings.used LEFT JOIN stores ON listings.owner = stores.id LEFT JOIN images ON listings.id = images.lid LEFT JOIN tags ON listings.id = tags.lid 

 
WHERE listings.id > 0
GROUP BY images.lid 

 
ORDER BY listings.id ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

I tried to change some vars on my.ini but nothing changed.

```
innodb-buffer-pool-size=1G
query-cache-limit=20M
query-cache-size=128M
query-cache-type=1
read-buffer-size=32M
tmp-table-size=1504M
max-heap-table-size=1504M
thread-cache-size=30
open-files-limit=50000
```

Question is: Why this query is so slow on windows but not on linux? And my main problem is i have to work on windows so how can i make more faster this query as like linux?

Also specs of the both windows machines are way better than linux server.

Comment: ok .then what is the question ??

Comment: Is the content of the server the same?

Comment: Question is: Why this query is so slow on windows but not on linux? And my main problem is i have to work on windows so how can i make more faster this query as like linux?

Comment: There could be many explanations, but there isn't enough information in this question. Is there more data in the Windows database? Are the tables defined the same (indexes, etc.)? Is the version of MySQL Server the same on both computers? You showed some configuration from my.ini but are these values configured the same on your MySQL Server on Linux? Are there other programs running on Windows that would slow down the computer?

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is [known to cause a performance penalty](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) but that would not explain the performance difference on Linux.

Comment: After you said I checked mysql versions and saw that they are different. After migrating to MySQL version 8, the problem disappeared. Thank you Bill.

Comment: Moderator, Based on the previous comment,  Could you mark this case CLOSED?  Thanks

Comment: How much RAM on each machine?  What version(s) of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using too many `left join`s, especially there are a mass of records in each table of your MySQL database, which will greatly reduce the query efficiency.

Hence, your problem is obviously due to the query way of sql, rather than the kind of OS your sql query running on. And I reommend that you should perform several separate single-table queries and merge the results.

Comment: I can understand that, i mean maybe 4 or 5 joins can make slower my query but why it is working on linux very well then? I can get my results less than 1 seconds.

Comment: But your description of the situation is too weak to support someone else's judgment.

Comment: The speed of computation usually takes into account a lot of external circumstances... May be your local windows machine is running much other programs right now, which runs out of your memory or occupies too much of CPU.

Comment: As i said on the original post both my local pc and remote windows computer's specs is way more better than the linux server.